# JavaScript .length property giving wrong value

Tags: javascript

I have this program where I add values inside a newly declared Array called arr. But when I try to `console.log(arr.length)`, It gives me the value of `1` instead of `10` (expected value). Anybody can explain why is this happening?

```
httpRes.done(function (res) {
        if (httpRes.status == 201) {
            $('#salary_detail').empty();
            $('#salaryModal').removeClass('disabled').attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
        }
        else {
            var arr = [render_detail(res)]
            console.log(arr.length); // returns 1
            if (arr.length < 16) {
                $('#salaryModal').addClass('disabled').removeAttr('data-toggle');
            }
            else {
                $('#salaryModal').removeClass('disabled').attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
            };
            $('#salary_detail').html(render(arr));

        }
    });
```

And this is the function render:

```
function render_detail(res) {
    if (res.length < 9) {
        res[0] = `<span class='text-warning'>${formatter.format(res[0])}</span>`;
        res[1] = `<span class='text-danger'>-${formatter.format(res[1])}</span>`;
        res[2] = `<span class='text-danger'>-${formatter.format(res[2])}</span>`;
        res[3] = `<span class='text-danger'>-${formatter.format(res[3])}</span>`
        res[4] = `<span class='text-success'>+${formatter.format(res[4])}</span>`;
        res[5] = `<span class='text-danger'>-${formatter.format(res[5])}</span>`;
        res[6] = `<span class='text-muted'>${formatter.format(res[6])}</span>`;
        res[7] = `<span class='text-muted'>${res[7]}</span>`;
    }
    else {
        res[0] = `<span class='text-warning'>${formatter.format(res[0])}</span>`;
        res[1] = `<span class='text-danger'>-${formatter.format(res[1])}</span>`;
        res[2] = `<span class='text-danger'>-${formatter.format(res[2])}</span>`;
        res[3] = `<span class='text-danger'>-${formatter.format(res[3])}</span>`
        res[4] = `<span class='text-success'>+${formatter.format(res[4])}</span>`;
        res[5] = `<span class='text-danger'>-${formatter.format(res[5])}</span>`;
        res[6] = `<span class='text-muted'>${formatter.format(res[6])}</span>`;
        res[7] = `<span class='text-muted'>${res[7]}</span>`;
        res[8] = `<span class='text-warning'>${formatter.format(res[8])}</span>`;
        res[9] = `<span class='text-danger'>-${formatter.format(res[9])}</span>`;
        res[10] = `<span class='text-danger'>-${formatter.format(res[10])}</span>`;
        res[11] = `<span class='text-danger'>-${formatter.format(res[11])}</span>`
        res[12] = `<span class='text-success'>+${formatter.format(res[12])}</span>`;
        res[13] = `<span class='text-danger'>-${formatter.format(res[13])}</span>`;
        res[14] = `<span class='text-muted'>${formatter.format(res[14])}</span>`;
        res[15] = `<span class='text-muted'>${res[15]}</span>`;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Instead of passing `res` in function and doing `res[0] =`, create a local array, set values to it and return it. Mutating an object is not a good idea. Also you are getting length as 1 because of this: `var arr = [render_detail(res)]`. `res` has multiple values but you are encapsulating in inside another array. So arr[0] = res.  Remove square braces in this expression and it should work fine

Comment: The function might be returning null and the getting into the array and hence, the length is 1.

Comment: @Rajesh I see the point your are trying to make. Thank you, It works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're wrapping your array inside another array:

```
var arr = [render_detail(res)]
```

Don't do that, just assign it directly:

```
var arr = render_detail(res);
```

Comment: As an alternate, you may even suggest a pure function approach where `render_details` returns a locally created arrey instead of mutation

Comment: @Rajesh that's not the question the OP asked, but I am composing a separate (community wiki) answer that does that.

Comment: Great! Also, I'm aware OP is not asking that in question. Hence suggested it as an alternate

Answer (score 1):

Keeping this separate from the answer to the question you actually asked, your `render_detail` function could be written thus:

```
function render_detail(res) {
    const classes = ['warning', 'danger', 'danger', 'danger',
                     'success', 'danger', 'muted', 'muted'];
    const signs = ['', '-', '-', '-', '+', '-', '', ''];

    return res.map((value, n) => {
        const mod = n % 8;
        if (mod !== 7) {
            value = formatter.format(value);
        }
        const cls = classes[mod];
        const sign = signs[mod];
        return `<span class="text-${cls}">${sign}${value}</span>`;
    });
}
```

This returns a *new* array, where each element is transmuted using the inner function.   This function in turn relies on the repeating patterns in the data to add the necessary wrapper around each element.

Comment: cool trick, but I need the plus and minus sign on front and it seems your just add minus on every element. Thanks for the simplification though!

Comment: @MunkhturB. I just noticed that and am fixing that up now.

Comment: @Rajesh leave this alone, please.

Comment: Ok. Added explanation so that its easier for readers to understand. But your call

Comment: I made this community wiki because I don't want rep for it, not to make it a free for all.   Your changes clashed with an edit I was making myself.